# Replace the string in last occurrence using Python

Tags: python, string

I need to replace the string in last occurrence after splitting the string

I have tried the below way but it is giving incorrect output like `1.120`

below is the code which I have tried.

```
y = "1.19-test"


if '-' in y:
    splt = (int(y.split('-')[0][-1]) + 1)
    str = y[::-1].replace(y.split('-')[0][-1], str(splt)[::-1], 1)[::-1]
    print str
else:
    splt = (int(y.split('.')[-1]) + 1)
    str = y[::-1].replace(y.split('-')[0][-1], str(splt)[::-1], 1)[::-1]
    print str
```

The output I'm getting like `1.120-test`.  But here I need the output as `1.20-test`

Comment: Perhaps you could post some more examples of input and desired output, to give a clearer idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too complicated. Just store the output of the split, make your changes, and use [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to get back the desired string. **Edit** Based on the updated question, you also need to handle some extra characters beforehand. Assuming you only want to increment the portion after a `.` you can just keep track of the extra characters in a `leftover` variable, before applying the splitting logic.

```
y = "1.19-test"
leftover = ''
if '-' in y:
    temp_y, leftover = y[:y.index('-')], y[y.index('-'):]
else:
    temp_y = y

split_list = temp_y.split('.')
split_list[-1] = str(int(split_list[-1]) + 1) #convert last value to int, add 1, convert result back to string.
result = '.'.join(split_list) #joins all items in the list using "."
result += leftover #add back any leftovers
print(result)
#Output:
1.20-test
```

Comment: It is not working if we have ```y = "1.19-test"```. Giving error ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'```. The output I need is ```1.20-test```

Comment: I wouldn't have expected it to work with an input like that anyways. You may want to edit your question or ask a new one. " need to replace the string in last occurrence after splitting the string" Well, clearly thats not the last occurance with an input like that. This input should be added in question.

Comment: Updated the Question.. Please help me on this

Comment: @moong Alright, updated my answer.

Comment: It worked... Thanks @Parithosh Singh

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need something like this:

```
y = "1-19"

str1 = ''
if '-' in y:
    splt = y.split('-')
    str1 = "%s-%s"%(splt[0], int(splt[-1])+1)
else:
    splt = y.split('.')
    str1 = "%s.%s"%(splt[0], int(splt[-1])+1)
print str1
```

Comment: It is not working if we have y = ```"1.19-test"```. Giving error ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'```. The output I need is ```1.20-test```

Comment: Then modify above code to handle - and it will work

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked, I took reference of @Paritosh Singh code.

```
y = "1.19"
if '-' in y:
    temp = y.split('-')[0]
    splitter = '.'
    split_list = temp.split(splitter)
    split_list[-1] = str(int(split_list[-1]) + 1)
    result = splitter.join(split_list)
    print(result)
    print result+'-'+y.split('-')[1]

else:
    splitter = '.'
    split_list = y.split(splitter)
    split_list[-1] = str(int(split_list[-1]) + 1)
    result = splitter.join(split_list)
    print(result)
```